Changing the name of the _astro dist folder
I'm using Astro JS to build a google chrome extension, and I have a problem when using tailwind.
Apparently Astro adds the CSS files to an _astro folder in the dist but this causes conflicts with Google due to:

Filenames starting with "_" are reserved for use by the system.
Could not load manifest.

If I manually change the name of the folder and the link to it in the index.html file it works, but it's a pain to be doing this every time.

Is it possible to change the name of this folder in some astro config?
If it isn't, how could I automate this process for every build?


You can configure the assets folder in astro.config
defineConfig({ build: {  assets: 'custom-folder' } });
The above will generate a /custom-folder containing your assets inside your dist folder
https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/configuration-reference/#buildassets

I ended up creating a bash script to update the folder and the index file. It's not the cleanest way but I wanted it to be verbose and understandable.
#!/bin/bash
DIST_PATH=./dist
DEFAULT_DIST_ASTRO_FOLDER=_astro
NEW_ASTRO_FOLDER=astro
INDEX_FILE=index.html

echo "Moving '$DEFAULT_DIST_ASTRO_FOLDER' folder to '$NEW_ASTRO_FOLDER' folder"
mv $DIST_PATH/$DEFAULT_DIST_ASTRO_FOLDER $DIST_PATH/$NEW_ASTRO_FOLDER

echo "Upading references to '$DEFAULT_DIST_ASTRO_FOLDER' folder in '$INDEX_FILE'"
UPDATE_REGEX="s/\/$DEFAULT_DIST_ASTRO_FOLDER\//\/$NEW_ASTRO_FOLDER\//g"
sed -i -e $UPDATE_REGEX $DIST_PATH/$INDEX_FILE

